# Calling open cv python code for image display from C visual studio

Tags: python, c, opencv, cython

I am trying to call image display code of python from C using `cython`.

I had followed the procedure for creating `.c` and `.h` from `.pyx` and adding these into the C code in visual studio.

I had checked the python version on command prompt and it is `Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)`. I am able to import cv2 there on command prompt.

But when I call this .c and .h file into C code I am getting error

> NameError: name 'cv2' is not defined
>         Exception ignored in: 'read.readImage'
>         NameError: name 'cv2' is not defined

I had checked for python path is set in the environment. Still I am getting the error.

The code for read.pyx is

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cdef public void readImage():
    img = cv2.imread('dog.jpeg')
    print('reading')
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The code for souce.cpp in visual studio is

```
#include "Python.h" 
# include "read.h"

using namespace cv;
int main(void) {
    Py_Initialize();  
    PyInit_read();
    readImage();
    Py_Finalize();   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That might be your issue, but it is impossible to say without code https://stackoverflow.com/q/50382755/5769463

Comment: Compare the results of `import sys; print(sys.path)` in your python installation and in the standalone exe. I wouldn’t be surprised if they differ. You said the python path is set, to which value?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was issue of python path only. It is resolved now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same python version is installed twice at different location. The issue was regarding python path.